# how to render an emailbody

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-view, zend-mail

I'd like to use a view as an email body.

I tried this one:

```
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();

    $bodyHtml = $renderer->render(
        '/user/email/reset-password-email',
        [
            'passwordResetUrl' => $passwordResetUrl,
        ]);

    $html = new MimePart($bodyHtml);
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to render template "/user/email/reset-password-email"; resolver could not resolve to a file

My view-template is located in:
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render view as string, you need a renderer "`ViewRenderer`".

If you can get ServiceManager, 
then,

```
$renderer = $serviceManager->get('ViewRenderer');
```

Now,

```
 $bodyHtml = $renderer->render(
        '/user/email/reset-password-email',
        [
            'passwordResetUrl' => $passwordResetUrl,
        ]);

    $html = new MimePart($bodyHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the renderer from the service locator in the factory, and not instantiating it directly in the class where you are using it.

**Email sender class factory**

```php
class EmailSenderFactory {
    public function __invoke($services) {
        $viewRenderer = $services->get('ViewRenderer');
        return new EmailSender($viewRenderer);
    }
}
```

**Email sender class**

```php
class EmailSender {

    private $viewRenderer;

    public function __construct($viewRenderer) {
        $this->viewRenderer = $viewRenderer;
    }

    public function createEmail() {
        $template = '/user/email/reset-password-email';
        $variables = ['passwordResetUrl' => $passwordResetUrl];
        $bodyHtml = $renderer->render($template, $variables);
        $html = new MimePart($bodyHtml);
    }
}
```

I had the same problem (sending an email for password reset) and I solved this way. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I haven't tried with Factory classes already, so I don't know where to locate these classes.

Comment: well, this is going to be a bit too complicated to explain here in SO. I suggest you to give a look at Zend's basis tutorial: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/. On chapter `Database and Models` it talks about factories and how to use them. ;)